# Feel the Enlightenment!

Tags: riddle, word

```
Another riddle coming to you from the land of poets and thinkers!
Focus on word building this time. Well, as you might have thought...it's easy.
```

I decide if sweet or stinky
For most locks I'm the key
Go ahead and keep on piling
because even a child can find me

It's no vanishing
no clues here
no hiding there
It's no use

A man of words
participating right now
Teach him a lesson
and break his literal vow

Subdued by ships
Along lonely isles
I may result 
in stunning smiles

Comment: easy as a tag? is there a meta discussion around it?

Comment: it is gone :( 2 more to go...

Comment: "A man of words participating right now" - is this supposed to be some SE user??

Comment: "the land of poets and thinkers" - Greece?

Comment: @rand I was thinking Puzzling.SE

Comment: According to Google, the `land of poets and thinkers` is Germany.

Comment: @Cephalopod very good. 5 points go to Griffindor :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Read to the end. It's worth the journey.**

I decide if sweet or stinky

> There is a letter which makes the difference between "SWEET" and something stinky ("SWEAT"). It is A (or E).

For most locks I'm the key

> "E" and "A" seen as keys on a keyboard.

Go ahead and keep on piling
because even a child can find me

> Keep on piling means collecting/**counting** which every child can do. "E" happens to be the [most used letter](http://jumk.de/wortanalyse/word-analysis.php) in this riddle.

It's no vanishing

> Keep this is mind... we need to get rid of "ITSNO" from somewhere.

no clues here
no hiding there

> To be taken literally.

It's no use

> Oh, let's get rid of it now. "ITSNOUSE" -> "USE".

A man of words

> An educated man, an author or poet, of the Enlightenment era (see title) who is German (see preface). [See here for a list.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_literature#The_Enlightenment)

participating right now

> Participating presently... There aren't that many German Enlightenment authors, "LESSING" is one of them and his name reminds me of a present participle (it is).

Teach him a lesson
and break his literal vow

> This is too tricky, we remove the "ING". Because it's what makes "LESSING" a verbal part - it is his vow, his constraint. So we have "LESS" (there is also a small hint in *Teach him a lesson* giving you lesson >> *lessen* = take something away).

Subdued by ships

> Ships subdue the "SEA"/"C" and "PEOPLE" perhaps.

Along lonely isles

> Simply the letter C (="sea") along lonely isles " : ".

I may result 
in stunning smiles

> C: The word *may* also allows for something that is not smiling: :C

That is to say:

> We have "C"

So we end up with:

> E USELESS C

Now taking away what's useless,

> EC

Which sounds like:

> EASY :D

Now, look in the preface again:

Well, as you might have thought...***it's easy.***

> Lynch mob time!!

Comment: Without the hints on chat could this riddle reasonably be solved?  Some clues seem as obscure as @Oblong's answer.  Some are clever though like sweet/sweat.

Comment: @McMagister it _could_ be... it took over a week even with what is genuinely a fairly small amount of guidance. I personally think they're _too_ hard :p Writing these things is a learning process - it is the path to becoming an expert. The author always finds it surprising how hard everything is... and he is learning from that... and I am learning from that.. and hopefully you learned something too :D

Comment: I want to second that this riddle was too hard. In particular, it's hard because the clues are *hard to confirm* once you get them. It requires many steps to be done in sequence to get the answer, and the intermediate results don't mean much. And some of the interpretations are tenuous enough that I can imagine them applying by coincidence even if you're down a wrong path. (Though one like sweet/sweat are nice in that you feel like you definitely have something when you solve them.) When reading this answer, I honestly thought it was one of those humorous "justify a wrong answer" answers.

Answer (score 3):

I decide if sweet or stinky
For most locks I'm the key
Go ahead and keep on piling
because even a child can find me

> TEETH, keys have teeth, teeth are in 2 layers piling up milk/adult. Children bite or teething either way they find thier teeth.

It's no vanishing
no clues here
no hiding there
It's no use

> I I N N. Repition of the first words, theres no clues in here or there which are situated at the end of the sentence not the start.

A man of words
participating right now
Teach him a lesson
and break his literal vow

> M N.  A man of words in a debate trying to win to become the ALPHA male take the literal vowel, A from man.

Subdued by ships
Along lonely isles
I may result
in stunning smiles

> G. Gold is restrained by ships and buried on lonely islands.
>  L. Lonely isles is a body of Land.
>  E. smiles is an expression

Put all them together

> Enlightenment! rotating the i to become a exclamation mark

Comment: Some of this seems very far-fetched... I don't think even avi is evil enough to expect us to come up with this! :-)

Comment: @randal'thor I went as in a different direction and ended up in a pool of cyanide??

Comment: If your answer is right, it's one of those questions that calls for a lynch mob!

Comment: Dont worry guys! I havent seen anything correct in here :)

Comment: a correct answer within the first few hours would be unheard of